# find a string with _id and exclude a value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regex that I use to find a class:

```
about_class = about_key.match(/^(.+)_id$/)[1]
```

The above expression will match on `user_id`, `contact_id` etc.

I want to exclude the string `author_id`.

How can I update the expression to exclude `author_id`?

Comment: How about something like `second_author_id`?

Comment: I'm sensing an XY problem here. Are you trying to parse some standard format like JSON by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a negative lookahead:

```
/^(?!author_id$)(\w+)_id$/

> "foo_id".match(/^(?!author_id$)(\w+)_id$/)
["foo_id", "foo"]
> "author_id".match(/^(?!author_id$)(\w+)_id$/)
null
```

Comment: I'd keep OP's (very permissive) `(.+)`, though. Maybe he has hyphens in his ID keys?